# How to convert java to Spring XML bean

Tags: java, spring

We have a java web project with initial configuration in Spring applicationContext.xml. Please don't write that it is old style, I know.
Part of this configurations can be change vs admin panel of the application and we need to backup it from time to time.
Does spring have something like applicationContext.saveBean() or any any other way to save configuration objects into XML using Spring beans?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring caching with Ehcache:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-all

You are getting the option of caching on disk stores.
You also can persist your beans as java serialized objects.
Of course this doesn't generate an xml readable output.